# Why does swagger util `Yaml.pretty()` give different out put for same OpenAPI content in Windows and Linux OS? How to fix this to have same output?

Tags: java, windows, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

Why does the output of **Yaml.pretty()** differ between **Linux** and **Windows** when using the **Swagger YAML utility**, and how can I generate the same output for both operating systems using Java?

I noticed that when using **Yaml.pretty()** to generate YAML output in the Swagger YAML utility, the output can differ between Linux and Windows. I suspect this is due to differences in how these operating systems handle line breaks.

Can you explain the reason for this difference and suggest how I can generate consistent output for both operating systems using Java?

Code that I used

```
import io.swagger.v3.core.util.Yaml;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
....
public String getYaml() {
   return Yaml.pretty(this.openAPI);
}
```

output for Linux

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: PayloadV
  version: 0.1.0
servers:
  - url: "{server}:{port}/payloadV"
    variables:
      server:
        enum:
          - http://petstore.openapi.io
          - http://localhost
        default: http://localhost
      port:
        enum:
          - "443"
          - "80"
        default: "80"
paths:
...
```

output for Windows

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: PayloadV
  version: 0.1.0
servers:
  - url: "{server}:{port}/payloadV"
    variables:
      server:
        default: http://localhost
        enum:
          - http://petstore.openapi.io
          - http://localhost
      port:
        default: "80"
        enum:
          - "443"
          - "80"   
paths:
...
```

It has a different order for server variables enum and default property.

Comment: Why is the order important?